# Pronunciation of "Ine", as the name of the Saxon king in modern English

Tags: pronunciation, history, names

Ine, also rendered Ini or Ina, (Latin: Inus; c. AD 670 – after 726) was King of Wessex from 689 to 726 ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ine_of_Wessex)). This is a name still used today, apparently, but I do not find it in the *Longman Pronunciation Dictionary*. Three pronunciations at least can be found on the web: /'aɪn i/, /'ɪn.ə/, and /'ɪn/.

- [How to pronounce](https://www.howtopronounce.com/ine):  /'aɪn i/
- [BabyNamesPedia](https://www.babynamespedia.com/pronounce/Ine#English):   /'ɪn ə/
- [CharliesNames](https://charlies-names.com/en/ine/):  /'ɪn/

Is the pronunciation of the king's name known , and if so, which is it?  The modern English pronunciation is what is needed, but the Anglo-Saxon pronunciation and related historical facts are welcome.

Comment: Disyllabic, not /'aɪn i/ but like /'ɪn ə/

Comment: Are you looking for the Anglo Saxon pronunciation or the modern? Baby name websites would give the latter.

Comment: Yes, I understood "as the name of the Anglo-Saxon king" to be asking for the historical pronunciation. I have no clue how people who name their babies Ine nowadays say it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely /'in ə/.

The last [e] being pronounced is common in Old and Middle English before about 1400. Generally you're safe going with a schwa /ə/ sound for that final [e].

The [i] will either be a short vowel /ɪ/ or a long vowel /i/. In this case, [ine] looks like a conventional long vowel [i] followed by a single consonant and [e]. Think of modern English words that fit that pattern: pine, line, spine. In Old English, that vowel would be /i/, like the [ee] in *teeth*. (Nowadays, we diphthongize that vowel: /ai/ like the [i] in *pine*.)

Finally, if you want more footing, [The Pronunciation of Old English](https://people.uleth.ca/%7Edaniel.odonnell/tutorials/the-pronunciation-of-old-english) by Daniel Paul O'Donnell gives a brief rundown of pronunciation rules.

Answer (score 1):

There are several guides to Old English pronunciation. Here is one of them: https://oldenglish.info/advpronunciationguide.html